# Subtract days from a timestamp doesn't work with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, timestamp, gamesparks

I still can't seem to do what I want to do. My Data Base:
`{lastSeen: { $date: {$numberLong: 1614618000000 }}}`

I want substract days to value and selects the documents where the value of the field is greater than or equal. I test this:

`{"lastSeen": { "$gte": {"$date": { "$subtract": [ "$date", 1616000000000 ] }}}}`

but the response is 'no result to show' on Gamesparks.
When i test with this query:
`{"lastSeen": { "$gte": {"$date": "2021-03-13T00:00:00.000Z"}}}`
i have responses.
An idea ? Thank you.

Comment: Trying to use an aggregation operator in a non-aggregation context?

Comment: I don't exactly understand your idea.

Comment: My query should look more like this : `{"lastSeen": { "$gte": {"$date": { "$subtract": [ "Date()", 1616000000000 ] }}}}`

Comment: If what you said was your query was your complete query, it misuses $subtract because $subtract is an aggregation operator, not a query operator.

Comment: Ok. If $subtract is an aggregation operator, i can not calculate a value (timestamp - 30 days) to compare with timestamp in lastSeen.